# How to make RSS Feed Generator for ASRP Blog Posts in AEM 6.2

Tags: rss, aem, feed

Am looking for generate RSS feed from ASRP blog Posts from AEM to Integrate in Third Party Plugin,

does AEM have any OOTB solution for this ?

or we need to create a custom RSS feed generator ?

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/aem_rss.html

Comment: above link is import RSS feeds in AEM Page, but am looking for generate RSS feed from AEM for ASRP Blog posts, i can use it in Third party tools to fetch latest blog posts. hope it clears.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Adobe Forum Thread](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2337607), RSS OOTB feature is currently unavailable for AEM 6.1/ 6.2 Communities. So, you can create custom polling importer and do your stuff.

**To create custom importer:**

You need to define two properties in your importer class:
[image]

You can write your custom code in the overridden method.
[image]

When this service is deployed in AEM instance, your custom importer can be seen in the dropdown of the polling configuration. 
Polling configuration has a dialog, which you need to fill while creating your polling nodes. The below diagram shows how values given in config dialog mapped to node properties and then to `importData()` method:

[image]

The importData() method of custom importer gets the value of its parameter from this configuration. Thus you need to specify these properties in the dialog:

- **Type:** It defines feedType property of poll config node.
- **URL:** It defines feedUrl property. This mandatory field defines the source( or xml) to read.
- **Import to path:** It is the path where nodes needs to be created. It defines target property. This path is resolved to a resource and is passed in importData(). If target value is not provided, path of the configuration node is resolved.
- **Update Interval in Seconds:** It tells after how many seconds it needs to poll. Its default value is 1800 and minimum value is 300. It defines interval property of pollConfig node.

There is one more property in pollConfig node i.e. source which is concatenation of

`<feedType>:<feedUrl>`

After poling nodes are created, it will fetch your feeds from the given URL and store it in the targetted path.

Comment: small clarification, is this solution is for import Data from RSS feed ?

Comment: yes, but since the rss feature is not currently working, you need to write it down by yourself.

Comment: but am looking for export data from AEM to other via RSS.hope it clears