# How to create AEM content page from rss feeds custom fields

Tags: rss, aem, apache-felix, sling, jcr

My current project needs to create AEM content pages regarding a template from RSS feeds custom fields where each rss feed entry will be resposible to create a new content page. Also This feeds checker will check new feeds after certain interval.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create custom RSS feed so that the RSS feeds can be polled after a particular interval of time. You can use SAX parser for your custom fields (if your RSS is in XML format).

You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424779/how-to-make-rss-feed-generator-for-asrp-blog-posts-in-aem-6-2/48519711#48519711) about custom RSS feed. Let me know if you need to know more. [I'll update the answer.]